# React Testing Library not rendering all elements

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

What would be the reasons for React Testing Library to not render all the elements?  Are there any settings I missed?

Given a test such as the below.

```
it("searches with query entered", async () => {
    render(<Grid />);
    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "query" }), "query");
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Search" }));

    await screen.findByText("AU");
    screen.debug(undefined, Infinity);
});
```

This is the actual output of debug.

```
<div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; outline: 0; position: relative; overflow-y: auto; height: 0px;">
  <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 80px; width: 1800px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
      <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">NZ
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:40px">
      <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">NZ
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this is the expected output:

```
<div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; outline: 0px; position: relative; height: 60.9028px;">
  <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 5280px; width: 1800px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
      <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">NZ</div>

      <!-- this isn't rendered -->
      <div class="slick-cell l1 r1" title="">Auckland</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:40px">
      <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">NZ</div>

      <!-- this isn't rendered -->
      <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">Wellington</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your component look like?

Comment: Hm, I probably don't know how to share that.  It's a grid component from our internal component library, which uses jQuery-based https://slickgrid.net/ underneath.